# Rest-assured. Is it possible to extract value from request json?

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I'm getting response this way:

```
Response response = expect().statusCode(200).given().body(requestBody).contentType("application/json")
.when().post("/admin");
String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
```

I have a json in responseBody:

```
{"user_id":39}
```

Could I extract to string using rest-assured's method only this value = 39?

Comment: Try looking for info on how to parse JSON in Java -- to convert the JSON (in your case) into a Map.  You will, unfortunately, find about 20 different ways to do it, most of which are too complicated, but the Java gurus seem to like it that way.

Comment: Thanks, @HotLicks, I knew this decision, I was looking for answer with rest-assured only. It looks like it couldn't do it.

Comment: @Jay this is an old question but it seems to me that it is miss-labeled.  your title is "extract value from request json" , shouldn't it be "extract label from response json"? All the answers below assume you meant response ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the answer :)

Use [JsonPath](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#JSON_%28using_JsonPath_%29) or [XmlPath](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#XML_%28using_XmlPath_%29) (in case you have XML) to get data from the response body.

In my case:

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody);
int user_id = jsonPath.getInt("user_id");
```

Comment: indeed, in the official documentation: https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#JSON_(using_JsonPath_)

Comment: That's just plain vanilla JSON access.  What any JSON kit would do.

Answer (score 51):

You can also do like this if you're only interested in extracting the "user_id":

```
String userId = 
given().
        contentType("application/json").
        body(requestBody).
when().
        post("/admin").
then().
        statusCode(200).
extract().
        path("user_id");
```

In its simplest form it looks like this:

```
String userId = get("/person").path("person.userId");
```

Answer (score 27):

There are several ways. I personally use the following ones:

extracting single value:

```
String user_Id =
given().
when().
then().
extract().
        path("user_id");
```

work with the entire response when you need more than one:

```
Response response =
given().
when().
then().
extract().
        response();

String userId = response.path("user_id");
```

extract one using the JsonPath to get the right type:

```
long userId =
given().
when().
then().
extract().
        jsonPath().getLong("user_id");
```

Last one is really useful when you want to match against the value and the type i.e.

```
assertThat(
    when().
    then().
    extract().
            jsonPath().getLong("user_id"), equalTo(USER_ID)
);
```

The rest-assured documentation is quite descriptive and full. There are many ways to achieve what you are asking: https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

Comment: very usefull response, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

To serialize the response into a class, define the target class

```
public class Result {
    public Long user_id;
}
```

And map response to it:

```
Response response = given().body(requestBody).when().post("/admin");
Result result = response.as(Result.class);
```

You must have Jackson or Gson in the classpath as stated in the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.4.0/com/jayway/restassured/response/ResponseBodyExtractionOptions.html#as-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: This classic DTO approach is fine for small static responses. But the overhead of maintaining all that boilerplate is a drag for ad-hoc/dynamic/large responses.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use the response object as well.

```
Response response = expect().statusCode(200).given().body(requestBody).contentType("application/json").when().post("/admin");

String userId = response.path("user_id").toString();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
return jsonPathEvaluator.get("user_id").toString();
```