# How to get the value from a List using Rest Assured?

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to grab the first value of `courseNumber` for `studenId=123` using Rest Assured.

When I using

`.body("students.courseList.courseNumber[0]",equalTo(1000000000))`

I am getting:

```
Expected: <1000000000>
Actual: [1000000000, 1000000001, 1000000002, 1000000003, ...........]
```

There are more than 10 courseList for studentId 123.
Also is it possible to use regex to grab a particular element from JSON Response or how do I get the path of an element when I have a few thousand lines of JSON Response.

Sample Response -

```
        {
            "students": [
                 {
                    "studentId": "ABC",
                    "studentName": "Abcd Abcd",
                    "courseDescription": "AAJSHKJASSJAK LASNLKASA KJk;;K K;;KK;K;KL;K;",
                    "creditRemaining": 100,
                    "classStartDate": "20191220"
                },
                {
                    "studentId": "123",
                    "studentName": "DEFG, VBNH",
                    "courseDescription": "AAJSHKJASSJAK LASNLKASA KJk;;K K;;KK;K;KL;K;",
                    "classSchedule": 2,
                    "classStartDate": "20191220",
                    "slotsRemaining": 10,
                    "courseList": [
                        {
                            "courseNumber": 1000000000,
                            "courseName": "Chemistry",
                            "courseInstructor": "HGJ IOUIOU"
                            "courseCity": "New York",
                            "courseLevel": 100,
                            "description": "GJKJLKJLafgdhgf ljkllklk klyiyy mnbbnkljlkj 
       yttiuyuyuyoyo 
                         jhlkjkljkl"},
                    {
                        "courseNumber": 1000000001,
                        "courseName": "History",
                        "courseInstructor": "HGJ IOUIOU"
                        "courseCity": "New York",
                        "courseLevel": 100,
                        "description": "GJKJLKJLafgdhgf ljkllklk klyiyy mnbbnkljlkj yttiuyuyuyoyo 
                         jhlkjkljkl"},

        ]
        }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166137/rest-assured-is-it-possible-to-extract-value-from-request-json) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
students.courseList.courseNumber[0][0] --> will give 1000000000

students.courseList.courseNumber[0][1] --> will give 1000000001
```

Comment: when I use this it actually returns all the course numbers instead of the first one

Comment: Expected: <1000000000>
Actual: [1000000000, 1000000001, 1000000002, 1000000003, ...........]

Comment: Edited the answer. check it out. if it works, mark the answer as Correct